# Update set col to 0.00 if null or calculated value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to set a column to 0.00 if it's NULL, or, the calculated value if it's not null.

In the table below, the max score may not always be set, and the perCent col sometimes ends up showing NULL, which looks odd in the front end display.

I was trying the following sql, which does not throw any error, and does not work either, which means something is wrong.

How can I set this right?

**Table**

```
"studentId" "maxScore"  "studentScore"  "stdPerCent"
"1"         "100"       "25"            "25.00"
"2"         "0"         "0"             NULL
```

**Sql**

```
update scores SET stdPerCent = if(NULL,'0.00',TRUNCATE(100*studentScore/maxScore,2));
```

Comment: Why are you storing a calculation?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO So I don't have to calculate again when it comes to displaying.

Comment: As long as you're 100% sure the fields being calculated never change.

Comment: They'll change. New scores are added later for each student. This is just part of the thing for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find COALESCE to be easier to use (and to read) than the CASE WHEN:

```
UPDATE scores 
SET stdPerCent = COALESCE(TRUNCATE(100*studentScore/maxScore,2), '0.00')
```

Edit: and if you are just trying to fill the NULL fields and you know non-NULL fields were already calculated properly, this would make more sense:

```
UPDATE scores 
SET stdPerCent = '0.00'
WHERE stdPerCent IS NULL
```

Comment: You are right actually. I'm not trying to check if the table value is null. I truing to check if the calculated value in the sql is null before inserting it.

Comment: @jmenezes In that case, COALESCE is what you want. The function returns the first non-NULL value in the list. It can be used in your initial update/insert statement as well.